# Jupyter notebook forbidden access

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter starts with everything green until this pops up.

```
[W 09:25:48.054 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 09:25:48.055 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/config/tree?_=1510190747959 (127.0.0.1) 1.33ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

I can't see any files or folders in Jupyter Home screen. When refreshing the page I get a smilar error.

```
[W 09:29:01.631 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 09:29:01.632 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/terminals?_=1510190747965 (127.0.0.1) 2.37ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

It's been a while since I last used Jupyter on this pc, and I think I fiddled around with jupyter's ssl auth last time.

I have tried emptying .jupyter folder and reinstalling it with no success.

Comment: If you set up SSL, you need to access the notebook via `https://`

Comment: Yeah, solved it. Seems like I need to start with --certfile flag every time now, otherwise it won't grant access.

Comment: enable cookies on your browser that is permanent and easy solution for this

Comment: How did you acsess via https://?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: one time I enabled ssl on jupyter (with command `jupyter notebook --certfile=mycert.pem --keyfile mykey.key`) and since that moment, whenever I tried to start  jupyter without SSL, I could not access it with a browser and I got errors very similar to yours.

I noticed that when I start  jupyter without SSL and I run the browser in a private mode, everything works correctly.

Finally, I fixed the problem by deleting all history in the browser (it was Firefox, so I did <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>).